# Facebook Graph API not listing user interests

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user interests from Facebook for my app.So that am using Facebook Graph API.I saw many post asking this but no good answer is found..
How can i get user interests of the person who logs in with Facebook Graph API?
The permission for granting the token is attaching below

[image]

Here no user interests is listing why?
Can some one help to find a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Here no user interests is listing why?"_ Because it was removed after version 2.2 of their api

Comment: So no way to get user interests now ?